# Change Toolbar Text color in Xamarin (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, styles, themes, toolbar

I am new in Xamarin. I have create Theme for my project. That is below.

**Styles.Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

  <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

  <style name="MyCustomTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

In RegisterActivity it work well.It give me `#FFFFFF` as i expected. but in MainActivity it give me Black Color.

**RegisterActivity Image**

[image]

**MainActivity Image :**

[image]

I used same Theme for both Activity.I used this way.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "MainActivity", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    {
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView;

        private Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            this.toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(this.toolbar);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_action_toggle);

            drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.navigationView);
            navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        }
```

Any help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Spending 30 mintues I found the Answer I forget to Add `AppBarLayout` to my layout It will work when i add it.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Hi All, I want change the text color in the navigation bar. How can I achieve that.